# Generate cryptographically secure token in mySQL

Tags: cryptography, mysql

I need to have MySQL generate cryptographically secure tokens for me. To my knowledge, there is no built-in function for the purpose. Would something like the following suffice, or is this a foolish solution?

```
SELECT TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(UUID(), UUID()))
```

Comment: What are you using this token for? Why do you need to generate it within MySQL?

Comment: It's for a web service API key. I was hoping to generate the key within the DB, but can do it outside of their in PHP if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad idea. [GUIDs are designed to be unique, not random](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120523-00/?p=7553).

The GUID generation algorithm was designed for uniqueness. It was not designed for randomness or for unpredictability

Also from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2621604/569090:

> Do not assume that UUIDs are hard to guess; they should not be used
>      as security capabilities (identifiers whose mere possession grants
>      access), for example.  A predictable random number source will
>      exacerbate the situation.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I had that in the back of my head, but good to get it confirmed.